# Adding CC to mailx command using Runtime.exec

Tags: java, unix, aix

I am new to the AIX environment , and using the mailx command for the first time. I have understood the command inorder to send the email, but I would also like to include the CC email addresses.

I am trying to execute it through Java's Runtime.exec My command is as follows

```
cat EMAIL_BODY|mailx -s MAIL_SUBJ MAIL_TO
```

How can I add a CC to this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the variable `askcc`:

```
    askcc
        Prompt for the copy list. The default is noaskcc.
```

Read the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/mailx.html)  for more information.

You could use the `-c` option where you can specify comma-separated list of CC recipients.

```
echo "This is a test msg" | mailx -s Hello! -c xy@xy.com recipient@domain.com
```

This you can simply use it in your command from java's runtime exec.

Comment: but this would prompt for the copy list.
I am trying to execute it through Java's Runtime.exec
My command is as follows

`cat EMAIL_BODY|mailx -s MAIL_SUBJ MAIL_TO`

How can I add a CC to this command ?